# Java multithread race condition, Min and Max range of a value

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition, data-race

I have been asked this question recently in an interview, and I didn't get a feedback from my interviewer. I think the minimum answer is 2.

Given the following code, what will be the minimum and maximum value that will be printed in the line marked with 3 black '*'

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static final int THREAD_NUMBER = 10;
    public static Integer num = 0;
    final static Integer lock = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread threads[] = new Thread[THREAD_NUMBER];

        for (int j = 0; j < THREAD_NUMBER; j++) {
            int finalJ = j;
            threads[j] = new Thread(() -> {threadLogic(finalJ);});
            threads[j].start();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < THREAD_NUMBER; j++) {
            threads[j].join(); //todo add catch exception
        }

***        System.out.println("********* The number is " + num + " *********");
***    }

    public static void addOne(int id){
        // Critical Code
        synchronized (lock) {
            num = num + 1;
            System.out.println("add action thread " + id + ": " + num);
        }
    }

    public static void multiTwo(int id){
        // Critical Code
        synchronized (lock) {
            num = num * 2;
            System.out.println("multi action thread " + id + ": " + num);
        }
    }

    public static void threadLogic(int id){
            addOne(id);
            multiTwo(id);
    }
}
```

I tried running the code myself and got 2046 for the max number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, it is possible that each thread will be interrupted after it executed `addOne()` so that `multiTwo()` is executed first after all threads have run `addOne()`. This would mean

10 * 2^10 = 10240

as the result.

If each thread will execute `addOne()` immediately followed by `multiTwo()`, the result is the already mentioned 2046.

On a modern PC, the latter option is the most likely, but on a first generation Raspi that runs tons of other (unrelated) stuff at the same time, you may get something that resembles the first option at least partially – but only when `Thread::start` does not cause an immediate context switch to the new Thread.

Comment: why 9 * 2^10 and not 10 * 2^10 ? there are 10 threads

Comment: @JohhnyM – Because I have significant problems with basic addition? Of course it should be 10!

Answer (score 2):

Everything is synchronized and locked. That means you don't need to cover the intricate details of what happens when you access a field from multiple threads without Happens-Before relationships established.

That makes this not really an exercise in threading. That's good - generally these questions are annoying, in the sense that the useful thing to know is merely: "This code is wrong, because it violates JMM here and here, and this is how you do it right". Knowing what possible answers the code could give is esoteric knowledge that is utterly ridiculous to expect anybody to know - it's not useful information for the job, at any rate. You might as well fail someone from the interview because their fly-fishing knowledge isn't up to par. So, rejoice in that, I guess. It's a fair question.

This question boils down to:

- We start with 0
- We have 10x '+1' operations (increment).
- We have 10x '*2' operations (double).
- We cannot perform a 'double' operation unless that many increments have already been performed.

What's the MIN and MAX, respectively?

The answer seems fairly simple, and is a math/logic question, it has nothing to do with programming (some basic java knowledge is required to break down the problem to this, then logic is needed to figure out the answer).

You get the highest value by maximizing the impact of `*2`. Hence, by running the add operations first - that gets you to 9. Then double that 10 times, gets you to 9216.

You get the lowest by minimizing. Hence, 2046: Incr-double-incr-double - in that order.

It would be quite difficult to actually make a system give you 9216. Probably impossible. The point is, if a JVM prints 9216, **it is working fine** - the JMM (java memory model, a chapter in the Java Language Spec) gives a JVM the right to do that.

If you want to play around with it, get rid of the threading and replace the logic with random chance instead.

> I think the minimum answer is 2.

This cannot possibly be the case even if you play around with this code. For example, if you just remove all locking, the actual answer is **0** - NONE of the 10 threads are guaranteed to propagate their changes to the main thread, so the main thread is free to print 0 in that case. Any individual thread would see a minimum of 2 (and is likely to on modern JVM impls), but those worker threads aren't doing the printing.

> `//todo add catch exception`

I assume you wrote that? I would make a note on your file 'programmer has no idea how to do exception management properly'. You're in some luck - *a lot* of java programmers are completely clueless on this, but you're still getting past me only on the basis that hiring devs is hard right now so I need to be less picky.

`InterruptedException` does not occur unless you explicitly write code that interrupts. Given that you don't, and given that this is `main`, where you can, and should, and even did, just pile your checked exceptions into the `throws` line (or even better, write `throws Exception`) you're doing exactly what you should be doing. So, that note indicating you feel guilt about having done the right thing and evidently feel the proper way to write this exercise would have been to add a catch block there, indicates you *do not* actually know what you are doing. It's not really possible to know what the reviewers were thinking, but it's possible that threw that off a bit.

Or they are also clueless, and sticklers, and downmarked you for not doing it the (wrong) way they wanted, and write a catch block.

Here are a few rules of thumb to help with exception handling. Remember: *Rules of thumb*. That means they usually hold, but not always.

- If you don't know what to do in an exception block, **do not write one**, or if you're forced into writing one (due to a API design rule (see below) or because you're overriding and can't declare it in your `throws`), then you MUST wrap it. Do not, ever, just 'log it' or 'print it' and carry on. Yes, every tutorial under the sun and many IDEs default to it. That just means many tutorials and many IDEs are selectively braindead in this regard. Yes, for most exceptions, you wouldn't know what to do, and therefore this rule kicks in.
- If, looking at solely the signature of the method (the name, param types, and the class it is in - i.e. *not* at its code) it is rather obvious that some checked exception could occur, then that exception should be in the throws clause. e.g. a method named `queryPerson` that *does not* `throws SQLException` is virtually guaranteed to be badly written. However, the flipside is also true: e.g. a method called `save()` in class `GameState` should only `throws SQLException` if 'this system stores stuff in the database' is inherent to the design of the `GameState` class. If it is not, write your own exception and wrap your SQLException in it.
- If a checked exception cannot possibly even occur (Example: the `IOException` caused by `stream.read()` even when you know that stream is in fact a `ByteArrayInputStream` that cannot possibly throw it, or, `new String(byteArray, "UTF-8")` - UTF_8 is guaranteed by the JVM spec so that cannot possibly throw the 'I do not know that charset encoding' exception) - then the API is badly designed. Hence, do not write such APIs and if you're forced into using one, make sure to check the docs, there's often a better alternative. For example, `new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` is correct; it avoids having to deal with an impossible checked exception.
- When designing APIs, if some exceptional state seems virtually never 'handleable' by all use cases of your library/method you can think of, it should be unchecked. Similarly, if it is likely that some exceptional state can never occur and the caller knows it, it should be unchecked. Otherwise, make it checked.

Comment: I didn't add those comments, this is the original code I got from the interviewer.
Why if there are 10 threads, and each one running the add operation first, I would get 9 and not 10?

Comment: Nevermind, yes, 10. So, the max would be 10240.